# Android signing configs and conflict with splits abi

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, android-signing

I have an project that use `jni` library. for that sake i have this settings in my `gradle` file to split the apks based on their platform (and it's working fine):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.properties.put(signingConfig, signingConfigs.config)
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                            com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }

splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "mips", "mips64", "x86", "x86_64"

            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

Now I want to set a signing config so i can run `release` Build variant directly from android studio, so i added this to my `gradle` file:

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile rootProject.file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }

    buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                buildConfigField "boolean", "MOCK_MODE", "false"
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                buildConfigField "boolean", "MOCK_MODE", "true"
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
}
```

After this if i run the release build i will get the error `Error:path may not be null or empty string. path='null'`

**Note** that if i disable the split by setting `abi {enable false}` the sigining will getting placed and app run as it supposed, so i Think there is some **Complication** between splitting apks and signing config.

Any help would be appreciated.

tnx in advance.

Comment: could you give me the exact Logical for this?

Comment: @Karoly, Logical of what?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Are you sure it's about the signing? I think the conflict is arising only in combination with "minifyEnabled true". Furthermore, I get this error only if I try to run my code directly from Android Studio. Using "Generate Signed APK" works just fine. So my current workaround is: disable the abi split for instant runs and re-activate it for exporting the apks.

Comment: [Here](http://www.fongva.com/questions/1704290434104578) is an approach to change the setting automatically.


I also found [this very old, but similar bug with a recent comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37015037)

Comment: No. i'm not sure about it, and yes if i disable `minifyEnabled` the error will be gone, so as if i disable the `abi`. or removing the signing config. the problem is all of them wont work together and i can't figure it out which is the real problem.

Comment: After upgrading Android Studio and its dependencies to the latest version, the problem seems to be gone. At least in my case, everything is working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

update android studio from version 3.12 to 3.14, the bug is gone.